# Security check for item in array returns false every time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a type of data store in my model which includes an array of user ids, called "user". When doing CRUD operations on the documents I need to check to see if the requesting user is an owner of the document. So I have the following security rules set up.

```
match /tasks/{task} {
  allow create, read, write, delete: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.user;
}
```

The data object I'm giving looks like this:

```
{
 "user" : [
    "id"
 ]
 "title" : "Test Title"
}
```

and in the simulator I give the authenticated id to be "id". But, its giving this error:
[image: Error screenshot]

I can't figure out what's going wrong, any help or ideas would be appreciated.

**--UPDATE--**

I tried adding the below rule while looking for solutions and got the same error.

```
match /tasks/{task} {
      allow create, read, write, delete: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid && request.auth.uid in resource.data.user;
    }
```

Now it's still giving the same error, but on the first `request.resource.data` call.

This makes me think it's not able to get the `request.resource.data` object.

Comment: Does it work in your app, not through the simulator? Sometimes there are bugs in the console simulator.  If you encounter a bug, please file it with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I found the bug through my app but was testing it in the simulator. I'm not sure its a bug with firebase I was just thinking maybe I'm missing something that I don't know to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok idk why this made it work differently but here's what I figured out.

My code is below:

```
match /tasks/{task} {
      allow create, read, write, delete: if request.auth.uid in request.resource.data.user;
    }
```

All I did was add the `request.` in front of the resource call. Now it's finding the data in the request.